# Showing that the family of Borel sets is countably generated

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

I am taking a course in Measure Theory this year, and as an exercise from the lectures we have been given the following:

**Show that B(R) is countably generated; that is, show the Borel sets are
generated by a countable class A.**

We have defined the Borel sets as:

Let X be a metric space, the family of Borel sets in X is the sigma algebra B(X) generated by the family of open sets. A set A in B(X) is called a Borel set.

So far, my thoughts are showing that the Borel sets can be generated by the intervals [q, infinity) where q is rational.

I was wondering if anyone can help me formulate a proof of this, hopefully using my idea, as we don't get support classes or solutions and I would really like to understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Take the generating set $\mathcal{G} = \{[q, \infty): q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and show that any open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a countable intersection/union of intervals in $\mathcal{G}$, or their complements.

It's also well-known that any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open intervals, so now you've shown that $\mathcal{G}$ generates all the open sets.

So you conclude that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{G}$ is *at least as* big as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Obviously, it cannot be bigger (to be sure, show that all intervals in $\mathcal{G}$ can be generated by unions and intersections of open sets and their complements).

Comment: Just to check: 

(a,b)= U [q,inf)\[b,inf) where the union is taken over q>a, q rational?

Comment: in the union that should be set difference of the two, sorry :/

Comment: You can't have $b$ there unless you know it's rational. Try $(a,b) = \cup_{p> q > a} \cup_{p < b}(q, p)$ where $(q, p) = (-\infty, p)\cap(q, \infty]$ where $p, q \in \mathbb{Q}$ always.

Comment: Actually, im not sure that I am correct, since b is not rational and so is not a member of G, where am I going wrong?

Comment: How is your (q,p) constructed with members of G and their complements? I can see that (-inf,p)=[p,inf) complement, but what is (q,inf]? :/

Comment: I'm sure you could see it if you tried. $(q, \infty) = \cup_{r > q; r \in \mathbb{Q}}[r, \infty)$.

Comment: I got that just before you sent it back, so sorry for being silly! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are correct.
Consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and a sequence $(q_n)$ such that:
1) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$
2) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, q_n \leq x$
3) $\lim_{n \to \infty} q_n = x$
(such a sequence exists since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$)
Then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [q_n, \infty[ = [x, \infty[$
Therefore the intervals $[q, \infty[, q \in \mathbb{Q}$ generate the intervals $[x, \infty[, x \in \mathbb{R}$
And these intervals then generate the Borel sets (you can show it easily if you don't know the result already)